# What is wrong with following LinkedList code?

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am trying to attach a node at the end of linked list but the node is not working as I wish there are no errors but I am not able to figure it out where am I going wrong please help.

```
void attachEnd(node **hptr, node *newnode)
{
    if (*hptr == NULL)
    {
        *hptr = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        while ((*hptr)->next != NULL)
        {
            (*hptr) = (*hptr)->next;
        }

        (*hptr)->next = newnode;

    }
}
```

In main:

```
attachEnd(&head, newnode);
```

Assume that newnode is already created and initialized

Comment: _"the node is not working as I wish"_ is not a problem description. Why not? Nor is _"I am not able to figure it out where am I going wrong"_ What went wrong? What is right instead? You also should include all code needed to compile and reproduce the problem, not just what fragments you think are relevant. Please check the Help Centre to learn what is needed in a good question and why you should provide an MCVE.

Comment: yes I am using C and node is not working means when ever I append it to list only last 2 elements are shown

Comment: I would recommend you to create a [mcve], with emphasis on **complete**. That means making a simple example (e.g. adding 1, 2, 3, 4 to the list) and then displaying it.

Comment: `(*hptr) = (*hptr)->next;` -->> `hptr = &(*hptr)->next;` (and you dont need the `if ... else...`

Comment: @wildplasser would you please explain the logic and why there is  no need of if-else?

Comment: In both cases (empty list, non-empty list) you change the value of one pointer, a pointer that originally had a NULL value. So the problem reduces to: find the (first) NULL pointer in the chain, and change it to newnode.

Comment: @wildplasser hptr = &(*hptr)->next and what about this? what is difference between what I have written and what you have written?

Comment: Your version assigns to `*hptr`, mine to `hptr`.

Comment: @wildplasser what is order of execution of:  hptr = &(*hptr)->next

Comment: The same as for any other assignment : `x = y;`  **,** `ch= *str;`  **,** `p = q->next;` **,** `cp = &buff[3];`

Comment: I mean what is meaning of &(*hptr)

Comment: @wildplasser my instructor says hptr = &(*hptr)->next is not according to standards and it might lead to security issues if used at production since it gives you direct access to address of next? what do you think about it?

Comment: I think it is complete nonsense. "direct access to the adress of next" : you need to change- `>next`'s value somehow , and this can be done via a pointer. And it **should** be done via a pointer if that leads to simpler code. See my answer: there are zero conditions in it, except for the loop condition.

Comment: Well, see  my answer. If  `(*hptr == NULL)` at the start of the function, the loop will  be executed **zero** times. That is your `if (...) {}` part. Otherwise, hptr will be made to point to a ->next pointer. Until that happens to be NULL. That is the end of your list.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting mixed up with your indirection. Let's take a look at what happens here. You have this function:

```
void attachEnd(node **hptr, node *newnode)
{
    if (*hptr == NULL)
    {
        *hptr = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        while ((*hptr)->next != NULL)
        {
            (*hptr) = (*hptr)->next;
        }

        (*hptr)->next = newnode;

    }
}
```

Now, let's assume that you initialize `head` to `NULL`, and try to add a few nodes:

```
node *head = NULL;

attachEnd(&head, newnode1);
```

Because `**hptr == NULL` when you enter the function, you assign the value of the new node, and exit. So when you return, the value of `head` is `newnode1`.

Next, you add another node:

```
attachEnd(&head, newnode2);
```

In your `attachEnd` function, `*hptr` is not `NULL`, so you execute the `else` clause. `(*hptr)->next == NULL`, though, so you just assign `newnode2` to `(*hptr)->next`. All good.

The problem comes in the next call. There are two items in the list now, so you enter the `while` loop. And the first thing you do is:

```
(*hptr) = (*hptr)->next;
```

Remember, since you called `attachEnd` with a pointer to `head` (which is itself a pointer), what you've done is equivalent to

```
head = head->next;
```

And you've lost the previous value of `head`.

You need an intermediate variable to keep track of things so that you don't overwrite `head`:

```
void attachEnd(node **hptr, node *newnode)
{
    if (*hptr == NULL)
    {
        *hptr = newnode;
        return;
    }
    node *ptr = *hptr;
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = newnode;
}
```

Comment: The problem comes in the next call. There are two items in the list now, so you enter the while loop. And the first thing you do is:

(*hptr)->next = newnode; I did not understand this statement. In while loop I am executing (*hptr) = (*hptr)->next;

Comment: @PrathameshSaraf You're right. I got mixed up when I was writing things. I've corrected it. What's happening is that you're overwriting `head`, not `head->next`. See my correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
void attachEnd(node **hptr, node *newnode)
{
        /* There MUST be a NULL pointer somewhere in the chain
        ** Either at the beginning (an empty list)
        ** , or at the end
        */
    for (       ;*hptr; hptr = &(*hptr)->next) {;}

        // Once you get here *hptr willbe NULL
    *hptr = newnode;
}
```